# Spring Cloud Api Gateway Okta Invalid Credientials

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, api-gateway, okta-api

I have a problem about opening the login page of okta through `http://localhost:9090/authenticate/login`

I already get a page with showing a message which named **"Invalid Crediantials"**

Here is the screenshot shown below.

[image]

Even if I recreate an app in app many times, I couldn't solve the issue.

How can I fix it?

Here is the application.yml of api gateway shown below.

```
server:
  port: 9090


spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:9296
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ORDER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/order/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: ORDER-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/orderServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1 # how many requests per second a user is allowed to send without any dropped requests (1000 requests per minute)
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1 # maximum number of requests a user is allowed to do in a single second (500 requests per second)
        - id: PAYMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PAYMENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/paymentServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: PRODUCT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PRODUCT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/product/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PRODUCT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/productServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1


okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: https://dev-54315943.okta.com/oauth2/default
    audience: api://default
    client-id: 0oa6s2k5zyiKYoGwL5d7 // my client id
    client-secret: AqGnodb6VrX-eRiHnnZEE-HTZGUt383CVwLI344t // my client secret
    scopes: openid, email, profile, offline_access
```

Here is the security configuration shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class OktaOAuth2WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here is the controller shown below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authenticate")
@Slf4j
public class AuthController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> login(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser,
            Model model,
            @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("okta")
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient client
    ) {

        log.info("AuthController | login is called");
        log.info("AuthController | login | client : " + client.toString());

        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = null;
        try{
            authenticationResponse
                    = AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                    .userId(oidcUser.getEmail())
                    .accessToken(client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
                    .refreshToken(client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue())
                    .expiresAt(client.getAccessToken().getExpiresAt().getEpochSecond())
                    .authorityList(oidcUser.getAuthorities()
                            .stream()
                            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .build();
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.info("AuthController | login | error : " + e.getMessage());
        }


        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticationResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already found a solution if not here how I solved:

Sign in your okta developer account

go to Directory -> People -> Click one of the users. Make sure s/he is active.

then Assign Application -> choose/assign application and Save

try http://localhost:9090/authenticate/login
from incognito browser hope works